# Jenkins 2.273.1 "Editable Email Notification" sending emails with "$PROJECT_NAME - Build # $BUILD_NUMBER - $BUILD_STATUS!" content

Tags: email, jenkins, jenkins-email-ext

I was using Jenkins 2.222.x version and Editable Email Notification plugin to send emails about status of the job. It was working fine.
Later I updated my Jenkins version to 2.273.1, and I am still able to receive emails but like this:
[image]

Environmental variables are not replaced with actual data.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here: [https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-64659?jql=text%20~%20%22Check%20console%20output%20at%20%24BUILD_URL%20to%20view%20the%20results.%22](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-64659?jql=text%20%7E%20%22Check%20console%20output%20at%20%24BUILD_URL%20to%20view%20the%20results.%22)

Solution is to update "token-macro" plugin to latest version in Jenkins and restart Jenkins.